# Change TFS 2013 database tier name

Tags: sql, tfs, sql-server-2012

we got TFS 2013 install, it was successful install and working fine, until we need change the data tier database, so how could config TFS app server pointing to new named database, 
the database instance is same one, just changed it name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [tfsconfig registerdb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252443.aspx) and [remapdbs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee349262.aspx) command to achieve this rename/move scenario

```
tfsconfig.exe remapdbs /DatabaseName:data.tfs.contoso.local;Tfs_Configuration /SQLInstances:data.tfs.contoso.local
```

Ed has a [blog](http://www.edsquared.com/2011/01/03/Using+Friendly+DNS+Names+In+Your+TFS+Environment.aspx) on this too.